# Getting Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC while adding a new sheet in excel workbook

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

while adding a new sheet in a excel workbook, I am getting Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC:

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook m_objBook = null;
 object m_objOpt = "Test";
   m_objBook = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Workbook)(m_objBooks.Add(m_objOpt));
   m_objSheets = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Sheets)m_objBook.Worksheets;
   m_objSheet1 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)(m_objSheets.get_Item(1));
   m_objSheet1.Name = "Project List";
   m_objSheet2 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)(m_objSheets.get_Item(2))
   m_objSheet2.Name = "Project Status";
   m_objSheet3 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)(m_objSheets.get_Item(3));
   m_objSheet3.Name = "Pending items";
```

In below line i am getting error -  Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

```
   m_objSheet4 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)(m_objSheets.Add  (m_objOpt, m_objSheet3, 1, m_objOpt));

   m_objSheet4 = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet)(m_objSheets.get_Item(4));
   m_objSheet4.Name = "NewSheet";
```

Comment: you don't add directly to Sheets collection I think. I think you add a worksheet using the Workbook's add function